# Is is true that for sets $A,B,C$: $(A \cap B \cap \overline {C}) \cup (A \cap C \cap \overline {B} )=A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is is true that for sets $A,B,C$:

$$(A \cap B \cap  \overline {C}) \cup (A  \cap C \cap \overline {B} )=A$$

I tried:

$$(A \cap B \cap  \overline {C}) \cup (A  \cap C \cap \overline {B} )$$
$$=A \cap ((B \cap  \overline {C})\cup (C \cap \overline {B}))$$
$$=A \cap ((B \cup C) \cap (\overline {C} \cup \overline {B} ))$$

But don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, consider $A = \{1,2,3\}$, $B=\{2\}$, $C = \{3\}$

$$A\cap B\cap C^c = \{2\}$$
$$A \cap C \cap B^c = \{3\}$$

But clearly $A \ne \{2,3\}$

Answer (score 2):

It is not true; assuming you have a universal set $X$ and $\overline{C}$ refers to the complement of $C$ with respect to $X$, the equality is actually
$$A = (A \cap B \cap C) \cup (A \cap \overline{B} \cap C) \cup (A \cap B \cap \overline{C}) \cup (A \cap \overline{B} \cap \overline{C})\text{.}$$
To understand this intuitively, obviously each part of the union must include $A$.

Then, with respect to $B$ and $C$, one considers the cases with complements on none of them, one of them, and then with both of them. Union these to get $A$.

Comment: I'm not very sure about your formula. It does not include $A\cap B \cap C$.
Consider $A =\{1,2,3,4\}, B = \{2,4\}, C=\{3,4\}$. Then the right part of your equation gives us $\{1,2,3\} \ne A$

Comment: @Gabrielek Sorry, forgot to include that. Adding that in now.

Comment: Okay, now looks better! ;)